OAuth2 strategy after token exchange
I want to understand how the professionals handle auth. To better understand my problem I'll describe my app structure quickly:
I have a json api written in Go. Let's call it the BACKEND. I have a SvelteKit frontend, it has a client and a server side to it. Let's call it the FRONTEND and the FRONTEND-BACKEND.
I experimented a bit with auth now. My current solution works as follows: User navigates to login page. It redirects to Google's API for OAuth2. The FRONTNED-BACKEND takes the callback and now has access and exchange token. Those two are then send to the BACKEND. The BACKEND checks if a user with the email obtained with the access token exists, if not, one is created in the database. Then the access and refresh token are stored in a database with the user as a foreign key. Then I sign a JWT and send that to the FRONTEND-BACKEND.
Now when the user requests something from the FRONTEND it passes throught a hook on the FRONTEND-BACKEND and inserts the JWT. The BACKEND looks at the JWT. And here comes my first problem.
How do I make sure the user is still allowed to access data. I created a simple middleware that looks at the JWT and extracts the user_id and fetches a the User from the database. Then it also feels safer to fetch the roles of the user from the database while we are at it. But that made me realize that I'm really just using the JWT as a means to get the user_id from the request.
Now what happens if the user leaks the JWT, my only option is to block the user entirely because I can't invalidate all JWTs of the user because I simply don't have that list.
Now... it feels like what I really want is session IDs, but I read online that is very very uncommon for APIs to keep state, to have a table with session IDs.
Do I need an intermediate service that takes something from the user, creates a JWT or some other token with it. And then store a session ID linked to the JWT in a database? That way the FRONTEND would talk to the BACKEND with the session service as a middleman? The frontend would use session based auth, the backend would still use JWT?
